# extjs - Multiple delegations for click event

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, delegates, extjs4.2

How do I make it so that I can have multiple delegations? The code below is the one I attempted, but it didn't end up working.

```
listeners: {
    el: [{
        delegate: '.my-boundlist-item-menu',
        click: function(cmp) {
            console.log('1');

        }
    },{
        delegate: '.my-boundlist-item-menu-2',
        click: function(cmp) {
            console.log('2');

        }
    }]
  }
```

I also tried the following with no success:

```
listeners: {
   itemclick: function(record, item, index, e, eOpts){
                    if (eOpts.getTarget('.my-boundlist-item-menu')) {
                        console.log('1');
                    } else if (eOpts.getTarget('.my-boundlist-item-menu-2')) {
                        console.log('2');
                    } else {
                        console.log('3');
                    }
                }
  }
```

But neither method seemed to work. Thoughts and/or help on how to get this to function properly?

EDIT: As asked, here is my combobox code:

```
{
xtype: 'combobox',
displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
'<tpl for=".">',
'<tpl if="FirstName">',
'{FirstName}',
'</tpl>',
' ',
'<tpl if="LastName">',
'{LastName}',
'</tpl>',
'</tpl>'),
x: 10,
y: 60,
listConfig: {
    tpl: '<div class="my-boundlist-item-menu" style="cursor:pointer;padding:2px;border:1px dotted #fff" onmouseover="this.className=\'my-boundlist-item-menu x-boundlist-item-over\'" onmouseout="this.className=\'my-boundlist-item-menu\'" >Add New Contact</div>'+'<div class="my-boundlist-item-menu-2" style="cursor:pointer;padding:2px;border:1px dotted #fff" onmouseover="this.className=\'my-boundlist-item-menu x-boundlist-item-over\'" onmouseout="this.className=\'my-boundlist-item-menu\'" >Use Myself</div>'+'<tpl for=".">'+'<div class="x-boundlist-item">'+'<tpl if="FirstName">{FirstName} </tpl>'+'<tpl if="LastName">{LastName}</tpl>'+'</div></tpl>',
    listeners: {
        el: [
            {
                delegate: '.my-boundlist-item-menu',
                click: function(cmp) {
                            console.log('1');

                        }
            },
            {
                delegate: '.my-boundlist-item-menu-2',
                click: function(cmp) {
                            console.log('2');

                        }
            }
        ]
    }
},
id: 'end-contact',
fieldLabel: 'Location Contact',
labelWidth: 125,
name: 'idContact',
displayField: 'FirstName',
store: 'ContactStore',
valueField: 'idContact',
listeners: {
    expand: {
        fn: me.onexpandend,
        scope: me
    }
}
},
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Also pls include code for your view, so it's clear what's the elements hierarchy you have.

Comment: I just put up my combobox code. In essence I want the 1st 2 buttons that I create to have different processes. I'm doing it this way rather than adding it into the store as the data doesn't make sense to be in the store as it's just procedural.

Comment: Still not clear. You have a combobox. And you need to handle when user selects something in this combobox, right?

Comment: Yes. If you look at the listConfig parameter you will see I have a tpl for how the list is to be created. Before I do a tpl for loop I input 2 divs that get added to the drop down. Normally if it's just 1 div I use the listener and I can make it delegate to my added item and be done with it, but now I need to be able to differentiate between the two and can't see how to delegate different tasks to different items.

Comment: I think your main problem here - you're trying to configure delegates at the time when your elements (divs) are not created. You need to wait for either combobox `render` event, or event later for `expand` event and only then - drill down for rendered divs and attach event handlers to them.

Comment: nah, that's not the case cause when I only have 1 element it works perfectly. I'm just wanting to know how to expand it to 2 elements.

Comment: You don't need two for your task = you just need to recognize which button was clicked - check either class or element Id for that.

Comment: Right, but how would I do that... If I setup just one delegation I can give both of those elements the same idea and then a secondary id/class in order to differentiate, but I can't tell where in the returned elt (cmp in the case above) that I could differentiate between the two. I tried to get id/class, but nothing seems to work....

Comment: Try to log `cmp` that you're receiving inside handler. You can also add custom fields/tags - like name/data etc. Which will not affect your rendering but you will be able to retrieve it later.

Comment: I did try logging cmp and don't see any of the parameters..... There's a reason I asked the question =P cmp didn't seem to be returning any viable information and I couldn't find any additional documentation. cmp seems to be the event and normally it shows what was clicked, but since the dom is being modified the item getting clicked isn't the item that I had set and thus I can't seem to differentiate between the two still =/

Comment: Can you try to create fiddle out of it? Should not be complicated, but I think it will be easy to help you.

Comment: That should be it: http://jsfiddle.net/nypSD/ (Took a while as I'm building in Architect so I'm not used to creating actual code through ExtJS, but it should be close enough to the real thing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
el: {
     delegate: '.my-boundlist-item-menu',
     click: function(cmp, a) {
         console.log('clicked', cmp, a);
     }
}
```

`a` would contain div that being clicked.

Check documentation for `click` event - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-event-click

Second argument would container HTML target.

Comment: Why did you include `delegate`? I can't find this in the documentation.

Comment: I included `delegate` because original question contained that :) (I think... that was 1.5 years ago)

Comment: Thanks, looks like that option is no longer available in Ext JS 5. [Ext.mixin.Observable-method-addListener options](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-addListener). I think they renamed it to `element`. I will note this.

Comment: "delegate" - if I remember, correctly - is terminology from the .Net approach to event handling